# Toggle between active editor and previously active editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently lost some data, I am manually rebuilding some of it, this includes VSCode settings.

wasn't there a command for toggling between the editor that is active now and the previously active editor?

Searching around, all I can find are commands for

- Go to the previous editor
- Go to the next editor
- Toggle between terminal and editor

I could have sworn I had a command like this before, is there such a command?

something like "Go to the previous editor" and "Go to the next editor" would involve two hotkeys, I am just looking for a single hotkey.